# How to do serial communication between 3.3V and 5V devices using THT components?

Tags: serial, esp8266, 5v, logic-level, 3.3v

I know that there are many questions dealing with logic level conversion/shifting between 3.3V and 5V devices, but my goal is to do do this with standard breadboard parts, so either discrete parts or DIP/DIL packaged ICs.

The serial communication shall take place between an ESP8266 and a device that outputs/receives 5V TTL, and the desired speed is 38400bps, so I'm not sure if a simple voltage divider will be up for this speed, the same goes for using 4N25 optocouplers.

I know there are ready-made solutions like [this here from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1875) available, I would prefer to use generic parts that are available long-term.

I have used a MAX3232CPE for a similar project converting 3.3V to RS232 levels in both directions, does something like this exist for 3.3V to 5V as well (and in DIP/DIL packaging)?

Comment: What is the 5 volt device?

Comment: ... and what's the communication protocol between them? UART, SPI, I²C? If it's UART then a simple bidirectional buffer (one transistor and a few resistors) for both RX and TX would do the job.

Comment: @Andyaka: It's a proprietary lawn mower robot .

Comment: @RohatKılıç: Communication is done via 5V TTL UART protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic FET level shifter should do

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk1ycJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a doable and breadboard compatible solution - just one more question: I found a similar schematic here:
https://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/mosfet-voltage-level-converter
But they are using 10k Ohms resistors instead of 100 Ohms that you are suggesting. May I ask whether the difference is irrelevant? If not, in which situations should I choose 100 Ohms and 10k Ohms respectively?

Comment: sorry, it should be 10k (well definitely not 100R, teh default in circuitlab...). ill update the cct

Comment: Thanks! Last question: Do you have any idea up to what serial speed (in bps) such a setup would (roughly) be sufficient? Would I be stretching it with 38400bps or would there still be enough room? Just want to make sure I get a technically working, but rather unstable connection due to this kind of logic level shifting.

Comment: it will easily manage that. This circuit is surprisingly fast. I recently recommended this to a psu engineer. They had a level shifter (5V to 28V) and the resultant propagation delay was causing control problems. Using this cct recovered all performace. This was with a switching frequency of 200kHz (so the edges were at least 10x this)

Comment: Thanks a lot, also for your promt replies!

Answer (score 3):

Converting to a lower voltage can be done with any buffer that has overvoltage-tolerant inputs, i.e., one in the LV or AHC logic families (e.g., SN74LV125A, SN74AHC125/126/244/541).

3.3 V happens to be near the high voltage of TTL outputs, so converting from 3.3 V to 5 V can be done with any buffer that has TTL-compatible inputs (xx74(A)HCT125/126/244/541).

Comment: Thanks! I have come across these ICs at some point of my research but couldn't find them in DIP/DIL packages so that they could be used on breadboards. Or did I miss something?

Comment: One more question: Since I only have to shift two lines, but in opposite directions, it would mean that I would have to use two ICs, correct? Or are there ICs available that can do the shifting in both directions at the same time?

Comment: All of them are available in DIP, at least at big distributors like DigiKey or Mouser. And there are no small DIP logic devices, so you waste lots of channels. And you need two chips because they must be run at the target voltage. For just two lines, it might be a better idea to find TO-92 FETs (but the 2N7000 is not guaranteed to work at 3.3 V).

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks! Also for the info on the 2N7000 and 3.3V!

Comment: May I ask what would qualify a TO-92 FET to be working at 3.3V? If I understood what I read correctly, the RDS resistance is relevant here. Adafruit uses the BSS138 which has an RDS of 1,4 Ohms, but there are 2N7000s around with an RDS of 1,2 Ohms. Also, the load of a serial line is probably not to be compared with a situation where you use the MOSFET to drive a motor. But I'm no expert here, so I'd be happy to hear what I should be looking out for...

Comment: It's a question of the threshold voltage and how far above it you need to be to get a milliamp or so through, the threshold voltage itself is usually given for mucroamp drain current.   Realistically use a version of this on a breadboard compatible submodule, they are cheap, easier to source and reduce points of failure.